# mailchimp double opt in

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am new to this world and I can't seem to find where I can change the double opt in setting of mailchimp.  I know some people say to pass the value “subscribed” in the API field instead of “pending” but where can I make those changes?

Comment: Is this a programming question, or a configuration question?

Comment: configuration, mailchimp doesn't allow this setting to be disabled but others have done it so I was wondering if somebody here can help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are here to help you in **your code**. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of SO and read through the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to find out how to ask a question that is acceptable here.